# "Count if" in Crystal Reports (horizontally)

Tags: crystal-reports, report, countif

I'm using Crystal Reports.
I want to count all cells having "Yes" and all cells having "No" for each line as in following image:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Is it a cross-tab or standard report?

Comment: Its a standard report

Comment: You want to horizontal o vertical count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to count it using custom formulas. Create formula fields in report design, namely `ff_Evaluate`, `ff_Yes`, `ff_No` and set their values in formula editor like this:

1. ff_Evaluate (check each column and add to yes or no var)

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   numberVar YesCount := 0;
   numberVar NoCount := 0;

   if {table.T0} = "Yes" then
       YesCount := YesCount + 1
   else if {table.T0} = "No" then
       NoCount := NoCount + 1;

   if {table.T1} = "Yes" then
       YesCount := YesCount + 1
   else if {table.T1} = "No" then
       NoCount := NoCount + 1;
   ...
   ...
   if {table.Tn} = "Yes" then
       YesCount := YesCount + 1
   else if {table.Tn} = "No" then
       NoCount := NoCount + 1;
   ```
2. ff_Yes

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   EvaluateAfter ({@ff_Evaluate});
   numberVar YesCount;
   ```
3. ff_No

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   EvaluateAfter ({@ff_Evaluate});
   numberVar NoCount;
   ```

Now place these formula fields in your *Details* section and **Suppress** `ff_Evaluate` by `Right Click` on it, point to `Format Field` and then in the `Common` tab select `Suppress`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming columns named `T0`, `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4`.  Increase as necessary.

Create a formula (`TOTAL`), place it in the Details section (suppress it, if desired):

```
// create an array to contain the fields' values
Local Stringvar Array values := [{Command.T0},{Command.T1},{Command.T2},{Command.T3},{Command.T4}];

// global variables to contain tallies
Numbervar Y:=0;
Numbervar N:=0;

// generate tallies
Local Numbervar i;
For i:=1 To Ubound(values) Do (
    select values[i]
    case 'Y': Y:=Y+1
    case 'N': N:=N+1
)
;
```

Create a formula (`Y`), place it in the Details section:

```
// display Y after tallies have been generated
EvaluateAfter({@TOTAL});
Numbervar Y;
```

Create a formula (`N`), place it in the Details section:

```
// display N after tallies have been generated
EvaluateAfter({@TOTAL});
Numbervar N;
```

If necessary, you may use a summary field to total each value.